# can not get user info after doing authentication,facebookSDK, ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

I am trying to authenticate using facebook account by following

```
- (IBAction)logInByFaceBook:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"appDelegate.session.isOpen = %@",appDelegate.session.isOpen == 0 ? @"NO" : @"YES");

    FBSessionLoginBehavior behavior =   FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView;
    appDelegate.session             =   [[FBSession alloc] init];

    [appDelegate.session  openWithBehavior:behavior 
                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                             NSMutableDictionary     *dict  =   [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                             [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]   forKey:@"didLogIn"];

                             data                           =   [[SavedData alloc] initLogInInfo:dict];
                             [data saveLogInInfoToDisk];

                             if (session.isOpen) {
                                 FBRequest *me              =   [FBRequest requestForMe];
                                 NSLog(@"me is %@",[me description]);

                                 [me startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *my, NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"my is %@",[my description]);
                                  }
                                  ];
                             }
                             [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


                         }
     ];
}
```

However, i cant not get my `username` back and the console is displaying

```
Error: HTTP status code: 400
my is (null)
```

By looking up this [documentation](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Error_codes), 400 means `Invalid email address`..... and `my` is null so that I can no extract the `username` at all.....

I dont know why this happens...I try with the same email address with facebookSDK sample code and it works properly...

Getting lost now....Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong or missing something.